# Can't receive UDP packet on android?

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp, broadcastreceiver

I tried to implement UDP server on Android, i can send packets to server, but can't received it. Also i tried run receiver without android, it works. Where is the problem?

Local sender for Testing:

```
int send_packet(uint8_t* data) {
    int retcode;
    int socket_out;
    int broadcast = 1;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    socket_out = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if ( socket_out < 0 )
        return -1;

    setsockopt(socket_out, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcast, sizeof broadcast);

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_BROADCAST);
    addr.sin_port=htons(PORT_NUMBER);

    retcode = sendto(socket_out, data, sizeof(packet_data_t), 0,
        (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr));
    perror("sendto");

    close(socket_out);

    return 0;
}
```

Android receiver:

```
public void run(){
   try {
       byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
       DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(getPort());
       //socket.setBroadcast(true);
       while(true){
           DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length );
           socket.receive(packet);
           (new CallbackWrapper(getPacketReciever())).run();
       }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

ps I am running my application on a HTC Legend, not on emulator

Comment: I think i found it. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8407, http://www.flattermann.net/2010/09/fix-udp-broadcasts-on-htc-phones-running-stock-firmware/

Comment: Which port u use? the receiver side can receive your data? Your side can not get data from receiver side? Should use port > 1024 to avoid system service port, ex. port u can use is 10000 to send data, and port 10001 to receive data

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is on this line:

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(getPort());
```

You are assuming that the local host of the device is the same as the machine/computer, but the device has got its own network card, consequently having his own IP in any network, and his own network address IP, which is his own. The device is not reachable through just a port of your machine.

Comment: Look, i send broadcast request from server, on the all of local devices. I have tried that DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(getPort(),"192.168.1.255") for exmaple... but result is the same.

Comment: Try running it in emulator to see if you get any different results. I know that emulator needs to use another IP in order to communicate with your host machine, which maps to it. Also, is your HTC part of your network when you have it connected with your PC?

Comment: Yea, HTC is a part, it connected with wifi and it has his own IP in local network. "Try running it in emulator to see if you get any different results" - will try.